# Google Maps API. Принадлежность точки полигону

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Суть в следующем - есть несколько полигонов, районы города. Есть адрес на карте.  Нужно определить входит ли этот адрес в какой-либо район. Адрес приводится к точке на карте, т.е. по факту мы имеем массив точек задающих полигон и нужно определить входит ли точка соответствующая адресу в полигон. Можно это сделать как-то средствами GMap API? Или только если вручную высчитывать?

Comment: я бы использовал GL тессиляцию полигона и проверку вхождения точки в треугольники. Только GL, только хардкор =)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого есть специально обученный метод `google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation()`

```
var map, polygon;
// тут создаем карту
// map = ...
polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [
        {lat: 55.12, lng: 37.11},
        {lat: 55.99, lng: 37.54},
        {lat: 55.17, lng: 38.07}
    ]
});
if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation({lat: 55.76, lng: 37.64}, polygon)) {
    alert('Объект внутри района');
} else {
    alert('Объект вне района');
}
```

См. также [google.maps.geometry.poly](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=ru#poly)

Comment: Вооо, то что надо. Благодарю. А то никак не мог найти эту функцию.